# stripslashes ,get_option not working

Tags: php, wordpress

why this code not working in new version of wordpress?

```
update_option('header_ads',$_POST[header_ads]);    
<textarea name="header_ads" dir="ltr"><?=stripslashes(get_option('header_ads')) ?></textarea>
```

this code display textbox but textbox is not empty and when typing text into that and post Does not change .

[image]

It happened after the update WordPress to the latest version

Comment: what about `<textarea name="header_ads" dir="ltr"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('header_ads')); ?></textarea>`. check once

Comment: it means that in php.ini file of your system/server previously short open tags are allowed (on) but now its off.  check here:- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

1: short tags (short_open_tag) are not enabled in php.ini

2: you're running an ancient (<5.4.0) version of php, thus you need short_open_tag enabled in php.ini for `<?=` to work (see the changelog here http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php )

3: your escape method is all wrong, stripslashes is NOT how you're supposed to escape html. see htmlspecialchars(), and make note of the flags `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED`